# (compelx analysis) Let $I_m = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{2m}}$. Calculate $I_2$ and $I_3$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let
>   $$I_m = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dx}{1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{2m}}.$$
>
> Calculate $I_2$ and $I_3$.

In studying complex variables, I have come across this question in both Churchill's and Ahlfors' textbooks on complex analysis. Where does one begin for an integral like this? Is it best to use residues and should one attempt to factor the denominator?

Comment: For $k\in\mathbb N>2$, we have $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1-x~}{1-x^k}dx=\dfrac\pi k\cdot\cot\dfrac\pi{2k}\cdot\sec\dfrac\pi k,\qquad\text{for odd }k$$ and $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1-x~}{1-x^k}dx=2\cdot\dfrac\pi k\cdot\cot\dfrac\pi k,\qquad\qquad\text{for even }k$$

Comment: @Lucian . Thanks. How did you derive those integrals? Are they commonly known identities?

Comment: For the odd case, the whole idea is to subdivide $(-\infty,\infty)$ into three subintervals: $(-\infty,0)$, $(0,1)$, and $(1,\infty)$, then to use substitutions like $t=-x$ and $u=\dfrac1{1+t^k}$ on the former, and $v=\dfrac1x$ on the latter, along with rewriting $x^a-x^b=(1-x^b)-(1-x^a)$. This will yield a linear combination of [beta functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) and [generalized harmonic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) $\ldots$

Comment: $\ldots$ at which point [Euler's reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula) for the [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) will come into play. As for the even case, use the [symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions) of the integrand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a possible starting point, write the denominator as 
$$
\frac{1-x^{2m+1}}{1-x}
$$

(There is justification of this, in that that form is an analytic continuation of the sum form.)

You then get the difference of two integrals that will look more like the sort of residue problem you are studying in your complex variables class.  For example, integrals like
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{1-x^5} dx
$$

Comment: Thanks, Mark. My confusion is that we have been dealing with integrals that have their points of singularity ABOVE the real axis but $\frac{1-z}{1-z^5}$ seems to have its singularity ON the real axis when $z = 1$. What's the best way to deal with that?